# C++ / Gcc - Stack smashing when a func returns a struct

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, stack

I'm actually having troubles with a simple program which is supposed to pass a struct through named pipes.

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>                                                                                                   
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "NamedPipe.hh"

int             main()                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                    
  pid_t         pid;                                                                                                 
  std::string   str("test_namedPipe");                                                                               
  NamedPipe     pipe(str);                                                                                           
  message       *msg;                                                                                                

  //Initialisation of my struct                                                                                      
  msg = (message *)malloc(sizeof(message) + sizeof(char) * 12);                                                      
  msg->type = 1;                                                                                                     
  sprintf(msg->str, "Hello World");                                                                                  

  //Forking                                                                                                          
  pid = fork();                                                                                                      
  if (pid != 0) {                                                                                                    
    pipe.send(msg);                                                                                                  
  } else {                                                                                                           
    message msg_receive = pipe.receive(); //Here is the overflow                                                     
    std::cout << "type: " << msg_receive.type << " file: " << msg_receive.str << std::endl;                          
  }                                                                                                                  
  return (0);                                                                                                        
}
```

My NamedPipe.cpp:

```
#include "NamedPipe.hh"                                                                                              
#include <stdio.h>

NamedPipe::NamedPipe(std::string const &_name) : name("/tmp/" + _name) {                                             
  mkfifo(name.c_str(), 0666);                                                                                        
  // std::cout << "create fifo " << name << std::endl;                                                               
}

NamedPipe::~NamedPipe() {                                                                                            
  unlink(name.c_str());                                                                                              
}

void            NamedPipe::send(message *msg) {                                                                      
  int           fd;                                                                                                  
  int           size = sizeof(char) * 12 + sizeof(message);                                                          

  fd = open(name.c_str(), O_WRONLY);                                                                                 
  write(fd, &size, sizeof(int));                                                                                     
  write(fd, msg, (size_t)size);                                                                                      
  close(fd);                                                                                                         
}

message         NamedPipe::receive() {                                                                               
  int           fd;                                                                                                  
  int           size;                                                                                                
  message       msg;                                                                                                 

  fd = open(name.c_str(), O_RDONLY);                                                                                 
  read(fd, &size, sizeof(int));                                                                                      
  read(fd, &msg, (size_t)size);                                                                                      
  close(fd);                                                                                                         
  return (msg); //I debugged with printf. This actually reach this point before overflow                             
}
```

And my struct is defined like:

```
struct                          message {                                                                            
  int                           type;                                                                                
  char                          str[0];                                                                              
};
```

I actually think that may be a problem of memory allocation, but I have really no idea of what I should do to fix this.

Thanks for reading/helping !

Comment: Hint: `assert(size<sizeof(message))` before `read(fd, &msg, (size_t)size)`

Comment: Also, why are you using `malloc` and raw pointers in C++?

Comment: You're right, I got an error at this point... Thanks for the hint !
(I am actually a c programmer learning c++)

Comment: I would abandon the `str[0]` train of thought in until you really understand the language a lot better.  That's advanced stuff and is hard to get right.  Just use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead for byte buffers.

Comment: The purpose of this training is to send an object containing a std::vector<std::string> and an int through a named pipe. I didn't manage to find any way to send the whole object and retrieve it, so I tried to split it in structures (message)...

Comment: `str[0]` seems like a flexible array member. if it is then it shouldn't be shallow-copied.

Comment: Isn't `message       msg;` declaring a locally scope variable? Wouldn't `return (msg);` attempt to return the address of the local variable which is gone on exit of the function?

Comment: @alvits no, it returns a copy of the local variable (which happens to be one int and 0 chars long).

Answer (score 0):

This is the root of your problem, your `struct message`:

char  str[0];

This is not kosher in C++ (nor is the way you're using it kosher in C). When you allocate a `message` on the stack, you're allocating room for one `int` and 0 `char`s. Then in this line

```
read(fd, &msg, (size_t)size);
```

you write beyond your stack allocation into neverland. Then you return your `message` object which would be just one `int` in size.

Change your struct to this, and it should "work"

```
    struct message
    {
        int type;
        char str[ 16 ];
    };
```

Comment: The "Hello world" right here is just an example. I need to send some variable str lengths

Comment: Regardless, what you're doing will not work. That's just not how memory works. What I showed will get your example code to not trample all over memory, though you also need to adjust your size calculation in your send function.